# Как вывести адрес первого и последнего элемента списка Си

Tags: c, list

Помогите пожалуйста. Как адрес первого и последнего элемента односвязного списка. Язык С

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 
struct Tlist
{
    int num;
    struct Tlist* next;
};

typedef struct Tlist list;



list * pushFront(list* head)
{
    list* temp = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    scanf("%d", &temp->num);
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
    return head;
}



list* pushBack(list* head)
{
    list* current = head;
    list *temp = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        while (current->next != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        scanf("%d", &temp->num);
        current->next = temp;
        temp->next = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        head = temp;
        head->next = NULL;
        scanf("%d", &temp->num);
        return head;
    }
}

void printlist(list* head)
{
    list* current = head;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty");
    }
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", current->num);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    list* head = NULL;
    int choice;
    
    do
    {
        printf("zapolnennie spiska prodolzhyt? 1-yeas 2-no\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            head = pushBack(head);
            break;
        case 2:
            
            printlist(head);
            break;
        }

    } while (choice!=2);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void printaddrfirst(list* head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        printf("list is empty");
    else
        printf("%p ", & head->num);
}

void printaddrlast(list* head)
{
    if (head == NULL){
        printf("list is empty");
        return;}
    list * li ;
    list * ne ;
    ne = head ;
    do {
      li = ne ;
      ne = li -> next ;
    } while ( ne ) ;
    printf("%p ", & li->num);
}
```